# Information about progress of executable procedure - possible?

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, netezza

I am writing here as I was unable to find information while googling. I have an SQL procedure which takes about 2h to execute, sometimes longer and sometimes shorter amount of time. I was wondering whether there is an option to monitor progress of the procedure while it's being executed?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to have a logging table built to measure the progress and insert a date time record when the procedure hits a specific line, the table will be updated as the procedure runs.

```
CREATE TABLE MONITOR
(
ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
STEP_NUMBER INT,
EXECUTION_DT DATETIME
)

CREATE PROC SPX_MEASURE_PROGRESS

AS

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'
INSERT INTO MONITOR VALUES(1,GETDATE())
PRINT 'STEP 1'
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'
PRINT 'STEP 2'
INSERT INTO MONITOR VALUES(2,GETDATE())
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'
PRINT 'STEP 3'
INSERT INTO MONITOR VALUES(3,GETDATE())


EXEC DBO.SPX_MEASURE_PROGRESS

SELECT * FROM MONITOR
```

[image]